# makecell conflicts with xcolor

Tags: packages, incompatibility

In this minimum working example, `makecell` conflicts with the `table` option inside the `xcolor` package. However, it does not conflict on the system of one of my friends although we have exactly the same vanilla `TeXLive` version!!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

This is a table

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
  1 & \makecell{Dataset\\Size}\\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your update levels are not the same. Make sure your texlive is fully up to date then try again. There has been updates to the array package which needed to propagate to colortbl (which is loaded bt the table option from xcolor), those colortbl updates where faulty and has already been fixed

Comment: We both are up to date. We both use:

sudo tlmgr update --self
sudo tlmgr update --all

Comment: Are you 100% sure have you run the update programme? Also try adding `\listfiles` before document class then you get a list of files and versions in the log

Comment: In fact, I am very surprised. Last time I updated was last week (and I usually update daily); at that time I had the error and my friend did not. Now, I decided to update before replying you. The error gone!! I do not know what is going one.

Comment: colortbl was updated on the 12th of this month to match a change to array package that went out with the latex release the week before, so between those two dates it did not work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: none of the answers to that question mention that this problem has been patched, so marking this as a duplicate does not currently seem helpful.

Comment: Thanks so much for explaining the reason. But the weird thing is that it was working with the system of my friend, who used to update as well. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: `makecell` loads `array` so this is a duplicate

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think that is not the correct duplicate (it is from april).

Comment: After updating, the problem gone. Thanks so much